# What happens when an ArrayList of Runnable objects is cleared?

Tags: java

Say you have an `ArrayList` of objects implementing the `Runnable` interface. What happens to those objects if you call `ArrayList.clear()`? Will they finish their `run()` methods?

Is this a threadsafe operation? If not, what is a threadsafe alternative?

Comment: Why not try it and look what happens? Hint: when does the garbage collector deems an object appropiate for deletion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling [`ArrayList.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear--) has no affect whatsoever on the objects it contains. It just drops the references that it has to those objects. It is not a threadsafe operation as `ArrayList` is not a threadsafe collection.

You can either use appropriate locking whenever mutating the state of the `ArrayList` (`synchronized` or one of the [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) implementations), you can wrap your `ArrayList` using [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-), or you can switch to a threadsafe collection such as [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer.